# Double foreach loop with where condition in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have relations like this

```
User->hasMany->reviews
Review->belongsTo->user

Review->hasMany->ReviewAnswer
ReviewAnswer->belongsTo->Review
```

Now I try to display answers for specific review. My reviewAnswer table looks like:

```
Id, review ID, text
```

But the problem is when I do that:

```
@foreach($user->reviews as $data)
  @foreach($data->reviewAnswers->where('review_id', $data->id) as $answer)
    {{$answer->text}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Then reviews displays okay, but I get the same answers for every review. How to repair that?

Comment: You shouldnt have to specify ->where('review_id', $data->id) in your 2nd loop. $data->reviewAnswers will retrieve the collection of all ReviewAnswer for that Review

Comment: check with ` {{var_dump($answer)}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to check if all the relationships are correct. In this example, I assume that your models are stored in your `app` folder.

First, your `User` model should have `reviews`

```
public function reviews() {
    return $this->hasMany("App\Review", "user_id", "id");
}
```

Next, set up your `Review` model to have `answers`

```
public function answers() {
    return $this->hasMany("App\ReviewAnswer", "review_id", "id");
}
```

Then this is how you'll get all `users` with their respective `reviews` and `answers`

```
$users = User::with("reviews.answers")->get();
```

Finally, peform the loop in your `view`

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @foreach($user->reviews as $review)
        @foreach($review->answers as $answer)
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hasManyThrough() option which the eloquent models provide you.

Link: [Laravel Eloquent Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

This means in your case you would add:

```
class User extends Model { 
    public function reviewAnswers(
        return $this->hasManyThrough(ReviewAnswer::class,Review::class); 
    )
}
```

and then simply access it in blade as:

```
@foreach($user->reviewAnswers() as $reviewAnswer) {
    {{$reviewAnswer->text}}
}
```

Comment: Same result as before. Review1 <-answer for r1, r1b, and Review2 <- answer for r1, r1b

Comment: try adding the needed keys to the hasManyThrough function to ensure, that the relations are build with the correct data. 

something like: 
`return $this->hasManyThrough(ReviewAnswer::class,Review::class, 'review_id', 'user_id', 'id');`

Comment: I think that I am doing it in good way, but now the answers are 2x more

Comment: I can't follow up on that, sorry. could you rephrase that? do you now have Review1-> r1,r1,r1b,r1b Review2-> r2, r2,r2b,r2b ?

Comment: Nope, Review1 <- answer for review 1 (twice), answer2  <- answer for review 1 (twice)

Comment: are you sure the data within your tables is correct? The given answer is especially designed by the laravel folks to work in cases like yours.

Comment: Table review: id, user id, review, table reviewAnswer-> id, review_id, answer